# unable to view the contents or rename a partition

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive

On 2TB HDD, I had about 500GB unallocated space which was not available on PC. 
Recently, I connected this HDD through the router USB port as external drive and the partition became available. I started storing the data.

Now, I am connecting directly to my laptop win7 64bit and the partition is no more available as a drive. In the win7 disk manager I can see the partition mentioned as healthy partition but there is no drive label assigned nor a partition format (FAT32/NTFS) info. 
When I right click on that partition I get only delete option all others are greyed out.

Please let me know how to make this partition available on my Win7 as a drive (NTFS) without loosing the data. I am afraid I dont have enough hardisk space left to backup the data elsewhere format and use.

thank you

Comment: Have you tried a different USB cord and power adapater?

Comment: Sorry, I failed to mention that other 3 partition rest of 1.5TB are available for io. The problem is with that one partition of 500GB. When I reconnect it through the router USB port I get back to read that partition. Its only when I connect to laptop directly I dont get access to that one partition.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `Diskpart` tool to examine the disk's partitions and determine why Windows is unable to access it.

***WARNING: `Diskpart` can be very dangerous if misused and can wipe data with no warning if the incorrect commands are issues***

You will need to launch an administrator command prompt to use `Diskpart`.

The commands you will want are:

`list disk`

`select disk n` where n is the number of the disk

`detail disk`

This will hopefully highlight the strange partition and what is wrong with it.

More details on `Diskpart` here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415

Let me just repeat the important part:

## ***WARNING: `Diskpart` can be very dangerous if misused and can wipe data with no warning if the incorrect commands are issues***